how to send udp packet to specified host in omnet ++ with inet
my problem is host A is broadcast the udp packet to all hosts within the network , what i need is just to send it to the specified destination address host B. i used udpbasic app and udp sink.
please help me to fix this issue

Take a look at examples in INET, e.g. at examples\inet\udpapp.
